# Unable to mount SD card, Exits with error

Tags: mount, sd-card

**I am trying to mount an SD card onto my computer, but it just shows this error:**

```
Error mounting system-managed device /dev/sdb1: Command-line `mount "/mnt/usb-Generic-_Multi-Card_20071114173400000-0:0-part1"' exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1,
   missing codepage or helper program, or other error
   In some cases useful info is found in syslog - try
   dmesg | tail  or so
```

So what do I do? i am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my ACER AspireONE computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try to install the exfat support:

```
sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils
```

Then reinsert the card.

If it does not mount automatically, try:

```
sudo mount.exfat /dev/mmcblk0p1 /your/mount/point
```

Comment: Exfat? Will it format my sd card as exfat? because I need it formatted as FAT.

Comment: @NarRag This will not do any harm, but will not help euther. This will install exfat support.

Comment: I faced a similar situation today. Would it make a difference if i change the file system format of the card?